# react-navigation: Can the screens have different names then what is passed in the routeConfig?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a situation where I do not intend for the keys I pass in the route config to be presented to the user:

```
const routes = {
    'tab/Search': Search,
    'tab/Scan': Scan,
    'tab/Me': Me
};

const Nav1 = createBottomTabNavigator(routes, ...);

const routes = {
    'stack/Camera': Camera,
    'stack/Home': Home,
    'stack/ItemDetails': ItemDetails,
    'stack/SearchItems': SearchItems
};

const Nav2 = createStackNavigator(routes, ...);
```

I need to use these keys as identifiers for the screens in code so I can tell whether we're coming from a stack navigator screen or a tab navigator screen by checking `routeName.startsWith('tab/')`. Is it possible to change the display name in the UI? Thanks.

Comment: Are you meaning https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html#title?

Answer (score 0):

In your actual screen component:

```
export class Search extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Search'
  }

  ...etc
}
```

You can also use `tabBarLabel` in that object for screens within a tab bar.